# Terminal in Mac: Put files in FTP Server

Tags: macos, terminal

I put files in the FTP server using my Macintosh Terminal. I use the command

"PUT filename.txt"

while doing this the text file which is an UTF-16 gets to the ftp server but do not retain the DoubleByte characters (E.g: Japanese Characters). I believe this is because I did not specify a file format for destination.

What is the command to be used to specify the Destination "File Format" "Type", "Structure" etc.

Comment: Probably better to ask at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

The default FTP type is ascii.  Before you PUT your file, you might first change your type to binary.

Here is how it looks at my prompt:

```
ftp> binary
200 Type set to I
```

Comment: i changed it to binary but still the file is being displayed wrong. when i open the file the japanese characters look like "#()a?//" etc.

Comment: does the editor on the other end support utf-16, or are you doing a GET after the PUT to fetch the file back and open it locally on the Mac?

Comment: I am using Mac to place the file in one FTP server for our company. We have a software to view the files placed in the FTP server. The software is a GUI and I refresh and open the file to view it. I dont need a GET command.

Comment: The Editor on the other end supports UTF-16. The reason I know is that because I see some files out there which have chinese and Japanese characters. The files which are placed over there are placed by using SAP and not manually using Mac Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I used BBEdit to save the file as UTF-8 and then sent the file to the server. This worked fine.

BBEdit gave me the option to save the file as UTF-8 Unix format. When i used Excel, Access or anyother software which do not have UTF-8 unix format (they have UTF-8 Windows) as saving, the text file is getting issues . Unix gets crazy with non english characters with UTF-8 Windows encoding.